# wcf add service reference config

Tags: wcf

Adding service reference to the project does not affect app.config file. My Service exposes two service contracts via two endpoints. svc util did not generate config file too. What is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What type of client application do you have? Do you see your endpoints in WSDL? What did add service reference generate?

Comment: 1. it is WPF app. Also I tried to add service reference to Console App it didn't generate any configuration too. 2. Where can I cee WSDL? Add service generated classes like MyServiceClient and so on...

Comment: If you have enabled serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" in your service configuration you can use url of your service with ?wsdl query string.

Comment: This url (with ?wsdl) returns an empty page.

Comment: That should return XML document (don't open it in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add mex endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" ?